# cannot display the receive byte

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I have to do serial communication in win32. 
I can read no of bytes but cannot display the read data.

I have used following function to read the data

```
DWORD serial::ReadTest()
{
char inBuffer[BUF_SIZE];
DWORD nBytesToRead      = BUF_SIZE;
DWORD dwBytesRead       = 0;

ReadFile(serialHandle,
            inBuffer,
            nBytesToRead,
            &dwBytesRead,
            NULL); 

MessageBox(NULL,"ReadFile completed", _T("Read"), NULL);

return dwBytesRead;
}
```

I have done following things that displays the number of read bytes

```
{
DWORD dwReturnValue;
dwReturnValue = serialObj.ReadTest();
printf( "\nRead complete. Bytes read: %d\n", dwReturnValue);
char temp[255];
sprintf(temp,_T("%X"),dwReturnValue);
//to display in the static text
HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_READ); //
if ( hWnd )
{
SetWindowText(hWnd, temp);
    }
}
```

I have to display the actual read data. I have searched and tried different options like char* but it is not working . Can someone suggest me the appropriate way of displaying the actual data. I am using hex mode for sending in other side and i should receive hex data here in this program.

Comment: `ReadTest` needs to give its caller access to `inBuffer`.  The normal pattern for this is for the caller to allocate a read buffer and pass that in to a reader function.

Comment: Your `ReadTest` function returns the *number of bytes received*, not the actual data it received.

Comment: Hi can you give me a sample code to return the inBuffer value from Readtest and pass it to the reader function . Basically how to extract inBuffer value in the main function. Could you please modify above example that can display the actual data (inBuffer).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the `ReadTest` function, to have the buffer and buffer length as arguments:

```
WORD serial::ReadTest(char* inBuffer, const DWORD nBytesToRead)
{
    DWORD dwBytesRead       = 0;

    ...
}
```

Then you declare the buffer in the code *calling* the `ReadTest` function:

```
char inBuffer[BUF_SIZE];

DWORD nBytesRead = serialObj.ReadTest(inBuffer, sizeof(inBuffer));
```

Now the `inBuffer` array contains `nBytesRead` bytes.

Comment: thank you for your solution. I can display only the last byte of inBuffer[BUF_SIZE]. how to display all the bytes. I have displayed using loop and at the end only the last byte is displayed in the static box. how can we display all the byte in same static box. i am sorry if i am asking simple question , but i am new bie in programming.

Comment: If the data is ASCII characters you must put a 0 terminator at its end, then you can pass it to MessageBox or SetWindowText. If the data is not ASCII then you can use sprintf to convert it to a string suitable for display, the same way you converted dwReturnValue to a string.

Answer (score 0):

for example if

```
inBuffer[BUF_SIZE] = {0x24, 0x21, 0x23, 0x24}
```

I am trying to send hex value from the other side.

then i can print these values one by one using:

```
for (int i=0; i<nBytesRead; i++)
{
char temp[255];
sprintf(temp,_T("%X"),inBuffer[i]);
//to display in the static text
HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_READ); //
if ( hWnd )
{
    SetWindowText(hWnd, temp);
}
}
```

here i have printed each item. how to print it as a single block.